# AJAX not being called on load in PhoneGap 2.9.1

Tags: android, ajax, jquery, cordova

I am trying to load and parse an XML file onto a page in my PhoneGap application. My XML file is in the correct directory.

When I run page in Google Chrome using a Local Apache Web Server, the file is loaded and Parsed, but when I run the application on my Device. (Samsung Galaxy SII GT-i9100p) The script doesn't run. I have tried everything I can think of. The thing that has stumped is that it was working a few days ago, up until I changed the script to parse the data into a jQuery Mobile Collapsible.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
$(function loadXml() {
          load();
      });

     $(document).on('pagebeforecreate orientationchange', Application.updateIcons);

      function load() {

                $.ajax({

                    type: "GET",

                    url: "schooldata.xml",

                    dataType: "xml",

                    success: function (xml) {

                        var regionName;

                        var schoolName;

                        var schoolDescription;

                        var liHtml;

                        $(xml).find("REGION").each(function (index, Region) {

                            liHtml = "";

                            $(Region).find("SCHOOL").each(function (index, School) {



                                regionName = $(Region).find("REGIONNAME").text();

                                schoolName = $(School).find("NAME").text();

                                schoolDescription = $(School).find("DESCRIPTION").text();



                                liHtml +=

                                    "<li>" +

                                        schoolName +

                                        "<br>" +

                                        schoolDescription +

                                    "</li>"

                            })



                            $('#schoolcontainer').append

                                (

                                    "<div data-role='collapsible' data-theme='b'>" +

                                        "<h3>" + regionName +  "</h3>" +

                                        "<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='false'>" +

                                            liHtml +

                                        "</ul>" + 

                                    "</div>"

                                )

                        });



                        $('#schoolcontainer').collapsibleset("refresh");

                    }

                });

            }
            $(document).one('deviceready', Application.initApplication);
```